# python sklearn Logistic regression predicts all 0

Tags: python, regression

I've built a logistic regression for car loans which contains "is the loan in default yes or no" as the binary dependent variable, i am using around 20 independent variables, and the data set contains 3327 records.

I split the underlying data into a training set and test set. However after i fit the model on the training data and ask it to then predict for test data i get an output of all "0" when there should be some "1" outputs in there given the training set has roughly 12% of the time a "1" for the binary default or no default variable.

I've looked at the test and training sets which all look fine pre and post splitting (no missing values, category variables are dummies, and the training/test subsets correctly pick records at random so no breakdown there as far as I can see).

Interestingly the function "predict_proba" shows the probabilities predicted for getting a "0" is always high for each output element (0.7-0.9 probability). I'm not sure how best to correct this as i'd rather leave the default threshold at 0.5 but i'm not sure how to clear up this mess.

Is it simply a case of I need more data given the number of independent variables or am I missing something/ did something wrong?

Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.rc("font", size=14)
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
import statsmodels.api as sm
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="white")
sns.set(style="whitegrid", color_codes=True)


#open the file
data = pd.read_csv(r"log reg test Lending club 2007-2011 and 2014 car only no dummy trap.csv")
print(data.shape)
##print(list(data.columns))

print(data['Distressed'].value_counts()) ## check number of defaulted car loans is binary

sns.countplot(x='Distressed', data=data, palette='hls')
print(plt.show()) ## confrim dependent variable is binary


##basic numerical analysis of variables to check feasibility for model
## we will need to create dummy variables for strings
#print(data.groupby('Distressed').mean()) ##numerical variable means
#print(data.groupby('grade').mean()) ## string variable means
#print(data.groupby('sub_grade').mean())
#print(data.groupby('emp_length').mean())
#print(data.groupby('home_ownership').mean())

##testing for nulls in dataset
print('Table showing cumulative number of missing data points', data.isnull().sum()) 
scrub_data=data.drop(['mths_since_last_delinq'],1) ## this variable is not statistically significant

print('Here is the sample showing no missing data')
print(scrub_data.isnull().sum()) ## removed records of missing info, sample still sufficiently large
#scrub_data['intercept']=0 
print(list(scrub_data.columns))
print(scrub_data.head())

##convert categorical variables to dummies completed in csv file
## Agrade and Own dummies removed to avoid dummy variable trap and are treated as the base case here

X=scrub_data.ix[:,(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,22)].values
y=scrub_data.ix[:,0].values




X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=.3, random_state=0) 


print('Here are the X components', X) 
print('Here are the y components', y) 
print('Here are the X values of the training', X_train) 
print('Here are the y train values', y_train)
print('Here are the y test values', y_test) 

model=LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_train,y_train) ##Model is learning the relationship between X_train and y_train
y1_pred=model.predict(X_train)
print('y predict of train data', y1_pred)

print('Here is the Model Score', model.score(X_train,y_train)) ##check accuracy of training set
print('What percentage defaulted', y_train.mean()) ##what percentage defaulted
print('What percentage of test set defaulted', y_test.mean()) ##what percentage defaulted

print('X test values', X_test) ## check test subset values
y_pred=model.predict(X_test) 
probs=model.predict_proba(X_test)
```

Comment: With an imbalanced class problem, it's possible the model is set-up properly but learning to predict the most frequent class. If the predicted probabilities are reasonable, this is likely the case.  You could try adjusting the `weights` parameter in the model call to `LogisticRegression` ([documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict)) to boost the weight of the less frequent class. Or, you can take the predicted probabilities and define your own classification threshold.

Comment: Thanks caseWestern. I've updated to include class_weight='balanced' and i'm getting a better output which I can hopefully work with to improve - model score is 62%.
Just so that I understand the magic behind it, the balanced weight adjusts inversely proportional to class frequencies in the input data. So we are undersampling by dropping data from the over-represented class and that's the only change?